# heroku deploy NameError with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise

I receive the following error when running the command `heroku run rails c`. I've deployed to heroku and ran `rake db:migrate`

Error:

```
/app/controllers/Users/confirmations_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Users (NameError)
```

Heroku has also found Devise in my gemfile.

```
remote:        Using devise 3.5.2
```

I've got the following in `routes.rb`

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }
```

And I've generated Devise Controllers which are located in `app/controllers/users/`

The first line of my `confirmations_controller.rb` is

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
```

Any ideas on the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `confirmation_controller.rb` file should be under the `users` directory, not `Users`.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed to do. However, the challenge was that I had already changed the directory name to `users`, but git still saw it as `Users`. So I had to get git sorted.